# Maintaining 3 remote repositories in a single local folder

Tags: git, tortoisegit

Iam using Tortoise GIT. Is it possible to maintaining 2 remote repositories in a single local folder? I have a master remote repository and then there is a staging remote repository which is always much ahead of the master repository. I created a local repo and pulled from the master remote repo. Then i created a new branch and tried to pull from the remote staging repo and it is giving me more than 1000 conflicts and 3000+ modified files. How do i tackle this using tortoise GIT?

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly? Sounds to me like you are mixing up the meaning of repositories and branches.

Comment: i want to have a single folder in my local machine which can be used to hold all the 3 remote repositories in GITHUB. But am not able to do this because of the reasons cited in the main thread.

Comment: But are the remote repositories actually forks or branches of a single repository? Do they have a common history, or are they unrelated sets of files that happen to have similar names and similar code?

Comment: I think this is a very weird way to organize things...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is just a misunderstanding of `git pull`. Suppose your two remotes are called `origin` and `staging`, and the branch you're doing your work on is `master`.

Right now, you have `master` set up to track remote `origin`. That's fine. But now you're issuing:

```
git pull staging master
```

What does `git pull` do? It fetches the specified branch into `FETCH_HEAD` in the `.git` directory, then it merges it into your current branch. That's all it does -- a fetch followed by a merge on the default tracking branch (if the command is unspecified), or on the specified branch (if it is).

You are taking your staging repository's version of `master` and merging it into your `origin` repository's copy of `master`. As you noted, the `staging` repository is 'much ahead' of the `origin` repository. Hence the merge conflicts.

You're not doing anything wrong. In fact, tracking multiple repositories in one local copy is a standard operation in git (at work, I track 12).

Try this instead (again, supposing one repo is `staging`, one is `origin`, and both use the `master` branch):

```
git checkout -b development --track staging/master
```

This will checkout a branch called 'development' locally, which will be setup to track your staging repository's master branch. You can now issue `git pull` on this branch as much as you'd like, knowing that it won't attempt to merge production's `master` branch into itself, unless you explicitly tell it to.